# Android Native Application option not available in "Debug as" inside eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I'm having a really hard time setting up cocox2dx in windows os for android development...

I am already able to run the application, I am trying to in it as native android application but there is no such option to that.

yes, I searched for several hours how to make it work, no success at all..

[image]

any tips

thanks

Comment: Not sure about the `cocos2d` but to debug ndk apps you need to set `NDK_DEBUG = 1` http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

Comment: You can use ndk-stack tool with adb console. `adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym {project_path}/obj/local/armeabi` I tried once and I can tell you debugging though native android app is very hectic, quite slow and time consuming task.